# Pass Variable into escape_javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

This passes the string `productID` instead of the variable which == `5`. How can I pass the variable, not the string?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".test").click(function(){
      var productID = 5;
      $("#productModal").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'layouts/modal', :product_id => "productID").html_safe %>"); 
      $("#modal").modal();
    });
});
</script>
```

also tried:

```
$("#productModal").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'layouts/modal', :product_id => " + productID + ").html_safe %>");
```

This also just outputs `+ productID +` instead of `5`

Comment: As i understand you assign productID on frontend, but you try to render erb on backend with variable you assigned on frontend. Server render it first, and it does not execute any html/javascript, so it's not aware of your variable. It's unclear what you try to achieve, but the way you do it with this code is not possible. Sorry. Probably if you would clarify what you try to do i could give proper answer.

Comment: @Fedcomp I am trying to render a bootstrap modal depending upon which `product` a user clicks on. The modal should vary depending upon the `product_id`.

Comment: You should put bootstrap modal window with prerendered html and `visible: hidden` on the page html and then use bootstrap method to make it popup. You should only use javascript here to actually trigger it. Erb will render it alone, without any necessity of javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to fix the code you've provided, you'd be best doing the following:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".test").click(function(){
      var productID = 5;
      $("#productModal").html("<%=j render('layouts/modal', product_id: " + productID + ").html_safe %>"); 
      $("#modal").modal();
    });
});
</script>
```

*However* there are several big problems with this code.

---

**Unobtrusive**

Firstly, *why are you using `<script>` tags?*

This would suggest you've put this inside a view, which is very bad practice.

The most effective way is to use the [unobtrusive javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) pattern, which is what the Rails [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) is able to support:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("click", ".test", function(e) {
    var productID = 5;
    $("#productModal").html(productID); 
    $("#modal").modal();
});
```

This not only means you're able to use this code *throughout* your application (modularity), but also ensures you're able to call the correct

--

**Accessibility**

Secondly, you'll notice I have excluded the `escape_javascript` code above.

This is because *the asset pipeline does not handle `ERB` / `Rails` code*.

Javascript is client-side; Rails is server-side.

This is important, as when you call `render` etc - your javascript will not be able to do this unless it's called from the server, especially if the partial requires a variable which is set on DOM load.

For this, you'll need to use [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

```
#config/routes.rb
get "modal", to: "application#modal"

#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   def modal
      @productID = params[:product_id]
      respond_to do |format|
         format.js { render "layouts/modal", product_id: @productID }
      end
   end
end

#app/assets/javascript/application.js
$(document).on("click", ".test", function(e) {
   var productID = 5;
   $.get("modal", {product_id: productID}, function(data) { 
      $("#productModal").html(data); 
      $("#modal").modal();
   });
});
```

A small caveat here is that if you append `.erb` to the JS file (`javascripts/application.js.erb`), you'll be able to use `render`. However, this can *only* happen when the file is invoked; thus passing any variable to the partial will not work.

---

**Update**

Here's what worked in the end:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("click", ".testinggg", function(e) { 
   var productID = 5; 
   $.get("modal", {product_id: productID}, function(data){ 
     $("#productModal").html(data); 
     $("#modal").modal(); 
   }, "html"); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will read through it carefully. However the fix you provided for the current code still just passes `+ productID +`, not `5`.

Comment: Hmm okay. If you read through the rest, I'll make an update for you

Comment: getting error after clicking: `GET http://localhost:3000/modal?product_id=5 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Did you add the route?

Comment: hmm - can you do `rake routes` to see what the route is called please?

Comment: Right after devise routes, `modal GET /modal(.:format) application#modal`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97500/discussion-between-rich-peck-and-onichan).